# Creating Multiple table in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create two tables in my SQLite database. One table (exptable) gets created, but the second table (inctable) gives me an error of no such table.

Here is my datahandler code:

```
package com.example.pocketmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataHandler {
    public static final String DATE= "date";
    public static final String EAMT ="eamt";
    public static final String EPAYEE= "epayee";
    public static final String ECATEGORY ="ecategory";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME= "exptable";

    public static final String IDATE= "idate";
    public static final String IAMT ="iamt";
    public static final String IPAYEE= "ipayee";
    public static final String ICATEGORY ="icategory";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME1= "inctable";

    public static final String DATA_BASE_NAME = "expdatabase";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_CREATE ="create table exptable (date text not null, eamt string not null, epayee text not null, ecategory text not null)";
    public static final String TABLE_CREATE1 ="create table inctable (idate text not null, iamt string not null, ipayee text not null, icategory text not null)"; 
    DataBaseHelper dbhelper;
    Context ctx;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataHandler(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx= ctx;
        dbhelper = new DataBaseHelper (ctx);
    }

    private static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public DataBaseHelper (Context ctx)
        {
            super(ctx, DATA_BASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try{
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE1);
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS exptable");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inctable");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DataHandler open()
    {
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public long insertData(String date, String eamt, String epayee, String ecategory)
    {
        ContentValues content =  new ContentValues();
        content.put(DATE, date);
        content.put(EAMT, eamt);
        content.put(EPAYEE, epayee);
        content.put(ECATEGORY, ecategory);
        return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME, null, content);
    }

    public Cursor returnData()
    {
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DATE, EAMT, EPAYEE, ECATEGORY},null,null, null, null, null);
    }

    public long insertData1(String idate, String iamt, String ipayee, String icategory)
    {
        ContentValues content1 =  new ContentValues();
        content1.put(IDATE, idate);
        content1.put(IAMT, iamt);
        content1.put(IPAYEE, ipayee);
        content1.put(ICATEGORY, icategory);
        return db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_NAME1, null, content1);
    }

    public Cursor returnData1()
    {
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME1, new String[] {IDATE, IAMT, IPAYEE, ICATEGORY},null,null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Here is my Log cat:

```
05-20 07:09:29.097: E/SQLiteLog(1545): (1) no such table: inctable
05-20 07:09:29.097: D/AndroidRuntime(1545): Shutting down VM
05-20 07:09:29.097: W/dalvikvm(1545): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: inctable (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO inctable(iamt,idate,icategory,ipayee) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(SQLiteDatabase.java:1365)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.example.pocketmanager.DataHandler.insertData1(DataHandler.java:107)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.example.pocketmanager.Income$2.onClick(Income.java:72)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-20 07:09:29.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1545):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Change your database name and check. It might work.

Comment: thanx aniruddha. but uninstalling worked for me :)

Comment: Both means the same :). Glad it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove `try`-`catch` from the helper `onCreate()`. If there's a problem, don't suppress it.

Second, uninstall your app so your old database file gets removed. See [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Comment: @laalto- if i remove try catch block my whole code gets an error. problem is with table creation. is there an error in my code??

Comment: That's the point. You should be fixing the error and not hiding it.

Comment: but one table gets created. whats the problem with other one?

Comment: Possibly that you already have a version 1 database file on your test device/emulator without the second table.

Comment: can you me an example where two tables are created. it will help me understand

Comment: Your code looks good - just uninstall your app to remove the old database file.

Comment: yes thanx a ton.. uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me. you seem to be genius in sqlite.